# Why my Model Order_by ... Doesn't Work (data not sorted) (CODEIGNITER)

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3

### Im trying to show my data from Database in Order by DESC but it doesn't work, it's not sort my data.. (nothing change).. What wrong with my code ??? please HELPME solve this.

this my model **Tiket_model.php**

```
public function get_tiket() // semua tiket RELATION Begin here
    {
      $this->db->select('*');
      $this->db->from('tiket');                   
      $this->db->join('customer', 'customer.id_customer = tiket.id_customer');
      $this->db->join('kursi', 'kursi.id_kursi = tiket.id_kursi');
      $this->db->join('bus', 'bus.id_bus = kursi.id_bus');
      $this->db->join('rute', 'rute.id_rute = kursi.id_rute');                             
      $this->db->order_by("tiket.id_tiket", 'DESC');
      return $query = $this->db->get()->result();
    }
```

Additional information:

- I'm Using Javascript Plugins DataTables to View my Data

Comment: What is the result you get? Just saying "it didn't work" doesn't help us help you solve this.

Comment: my data not sorted .. (nothing change) bro

Comment: Ok just for fun, if you change it to ASC does it change?

Comment: yes .. is same result.

Comment: So just to be clear - you get the correct data, its just not sorted?

Comment: yes. i get the data.. but it's not sorted like the query builder i use... can you check my query builder. i think it wrong but i don't know alternative code

Comment: sorry.. im wrong bro.. hehehe it's solved now.. thanks for your attention..
it's not working because.. affected by plugin DataTables javascript

Comment: Good stuff... Glad you got it working :)

Comment: i think your are using `dataTable` show your datatable in `view`

Comment: @Yadhu,  Yep i use dataTables... its automatically sorted again my data from db.. so is affected result. 
thanks for your Reply..  is already solved.

Comment: @KimDev post your solution here which will be helpful to others

Comment: @Yadhu ..  Ok i will post it later..  cause im not using my laptop right now..  hehehe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED

Data not sorting because,  Plugin Javascript DataTables automatically sorted my data.

This is way to fix my problem:

```
<script>
  $(function () {
    $("#tabel").DataTable({
      "order": [[4, 'desc']] //which 4 is array of column you need to reference for sorting.
    })
  });
</script>
```

- I'm using code above, DataTables options for sorting my data instead Codeigniter Query Builder.
- For more Information [DataTables ordering (sorting)](https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/table_sorting.html)